# public void - button.setEnabled with if statement for my situation?

Tags: java, android, button, buttonclick

```
public void onePointForTeamA(View v) {
    if (foulCounterA == 5) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 1;
        scoreOnePointTeamA = scoreOnePointTeamA + 1;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
        displayForTeamAOnePoint(scoreOnePointTeamA);
    }
}


 public void foulCountForTeamA(View v) {
    if (foulCounterA < 5)
        foulCounterA = foulCounterA + 1;
    else
        foulCounterA = 5;
    displayForTeamAFoul(foulCounterA);
}
```

Hello there. First of all I'm pretty new to android development and java. I've searched quite a lot for this problem but couldn't find a solution myself. I guess I'm still learning. All I found out was about override methods. 
 About my problem; I want to add `button.setEnabled(true);` with "if" to my java file so my button will only be clickable `if (foulCounterA == 5)` and will be unavailable to click otherwise. 
 By doing that change I want to change its textView color which I know how to do it.

`android:onClick="onePointForTeamA"` 
 `android:onClick="foulCountForTeamA"` on XML file. 
`int scoreTeamA = 0;`
`int scoreOnePointTeamA = 0;` 
`int foulCounterA = 0;` on Java file.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You have 2 alternatives. set enabled(it it there but not clickable)  or set it invisible( it is there but it is not seen)?

Comment: Which alternative do you like?

Comment: not clickable one. I want it to be seen red which I'll do it after with adjustments to colors.

Comment: I have already added your solution try if it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should know is that the parameter `(View v)` for this case is a `Button`. `Button` is a subclass of `View`. You can cast if you want inside your methods to be

```
Button button=(Button)v;
```

BUT  that is unnecessary for you to set enabled or clickable behaviour.
**SOLUTION:**
Add the line **:**

```
v.setEnabled(false);
```

Where you want it to be disabled you can put `true` for it to be enabled.

OR

```
v.setClickable(false);
```

To set it unclickable you can put `true` for it to be clickable again.

Comment: I've just realised I've to use v.setEnabled kind of code cause I defined it (View v) Thanks for that. But atm when I use `v.setEnabled(false);` after one click, it disables the button. When `(foulCounterB == 5)` this requirement achieves, I need that button to be unlocked without click. Atm In order for me to activate is clicking it one more time so It will know that `(foulCounterB == 5)` but I'm not able to click it cause I've disabled it.

Comment: OKay I think we may have to add some new logic in your code because your method on click will not be called when a button is disabled or unclickable! Can you clarify the whole app logic so that we can solve it together!

Comment: Thank you for ur help. I've declared int values at start. There is one score for team A and it calculates this score with +3 +2 +1 scores (3 different button) extra one faul button. I made code to act like if faul button is not pressed 5 times, +1 score won't be active. so I've `int scoreTeamA = 0;` under MainActivity and many public void onClick (View v) which all changes scoreTeamA.

Comment: Okay now I have got you I think you already onclickable and disabled button never feel the click. So what we should do is to not set your button disabled or unclickable but instead we should define a boolean in class lets say `private boolean hasReachedFive=false` Then you should be changing this value to true instead of disabling the button! and check the value if `false` or `true` to find the real values.

Comment: could you give it a look on my github if its possible @Xenolion , couldn't really understand about that one. [here is the link for github](https://github.com/Akotar/ScoreKeeperapp)

Comment: I have checked your code its good but I could not get the place where you set the value as `v.setEnabled(false);` just go and edit it according to your logic and I am going to edit it so the button can be clickable due to a condition!

Comment: [here it is updated](https://github.com/Akotar/ScoreKeeperapp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/scorekeeperapp/MainActivity.java) line 222 and 228

Comment: I edit a file I guess you will have show a sign instead of actually disabling!

Answer (score -1):

```
boolean condition = (foulCounterA == 5);
button.setEnabled(condition);
```

OR

```
if(foulCounterA == 5) {
    button.setEnabled(true);
} else {
    button.setEnabled(false);
}
```